# What is the source or rationale for the sins listed in the Ashamnu?

Tags: yom-kippur, selichot

The sins listed in the Ashamnu do not seem to be all inclusive or exhaustive.  Why these sins and not others?

Comment: Well אשמנו, בגדנו, הרשענו, זדנו, מרדנו, סררנו, עוינו, פשענו, צררנו, רשענו, שחתנו, תעבנו, תעינו and תעתנו seem pretty inclusive.

Comment: @mevaqesh Do these line up with the aseret dibrot (10 Commandments), or shabbat, kashrut and family purity, or any other categorization or prioritization of mitzvot?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The 'Ashamnu' seems to be a poetic confession designed to be relatively short and easy to remember that includes several common sins, in additional to more general statements that include those not specifically listed.

Comment: Suggestion - see Art Scroll Yom Kippur Machzor. It provides a list of sins that fit each "category".