# The sins mentioned in על חטא - why those?

Tags: tefilla, halacha-theory, mitzvah, yom-kippur

[This question about the "אשמנו"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76679/what-is-the-source-or-rationale-for-the-sins-listed-in-the-ashamnu) list is still left unanswered.

My question is about the apparent inconsistency of the "על חטא שחטאנו" list - so many different categories of sins are listed in the ABC order (my division is approximate):

1. Direct and explicit sins DeOrayta:

```
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּגִלּוּי עֲרָיות: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּהונָאַת רֵעַ: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּזִלְזוּל הורִים וּמורִים: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּחִלּוּל הַשֵּׁם: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּכַפַּת שׁחַד: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּמַאֲכָל וּבְמִשְׁתֶּה: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּנֶשֶׁךְ וּבְמַרְבִּית: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בִּשְׁבוּעַת שָׁוְא: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בִּרְכִילוּת:
```

2. Derabanan bad Midos:

```
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּלָשׁון הָרָע: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּלָצון: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בִּנְטִיַּת גָּרון: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּכַחַשׁ וּבְכָזָב: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּשִׂנְאַת חִנָּם: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּעֵינַיִם רָמות: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּצָרוּת עָיִן: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּקַלּוּת ראשׁ:
```

3. Speach related:

```
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּלָשׁון הָרָע: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּבִטּוּי שְׂפָתָיִם: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּדִבּוּר פֶּה: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּוִדּוּי פֶּה: (maybe on Mitzvas Viduy?)
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּטִפְּשׁוּת פֶּה: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּטֻמְאַת שְׂפָתָיִם: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּשִׂיחַ שִׂפְתותֵינוּ:
```

4. Ways of sinning:

```
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּאנֶס וּבְרָצון: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בִּבְלִי דָעַת: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּגָלוּי וּבַסָּתֶר: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּדַעַת וּבְמִרְמָה: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּזָדון וּבִשְׁגָגָה: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּיודְעִים וּבְלא יודְעִים: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּמַשָּׂא וּבְמַתָּן: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּעַזּוּת מֶצַח:
```

5. The rest I couldn't categorize:

```
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּאִמּוּץ הַלֵּב: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּהַרְהור הַלֵּב: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בִּוְעִידַת זְנוּת: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּחזֶק יָד: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּיֵצֶר הָרָע: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּשִׂקּוּר עָיִן: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בִּפְרִיקַת עול: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בִּפְלִילוּת: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בִּצְדִיַּת רֵעַ: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּקַשְׁיוּת ערֶף: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּרִיצַת רַגְלַיִם לְהָרַע: 
עַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בִּתְשׂוּמֶת יָד: 
וְעַל חֵטְא שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ בְּתִמְהון לֵבָב:
```

I have a logical mindset and try to understand why the Sages chose those items specifically (besides fitting the ABC).

1. The list of sins Deoraytah is strange, why those and not other like Shabbat (שמירת שבת sounds more important than שיקור עין), Bitul Torah (ביטול תורה is one of the most stringent sins, instead of בבלי דעת).
2. There are 7 speech related "sins" and none of them is Deorayta vs only one במאכל ובמשתה and there are so many food Deoraytot.
3. Most of the sins (#5) are impossible to decipher in plain Hebrew (as a native speaker).

Do interpreters explain why those sins were chosen specifically for every letter?

Comment: You think Lashon HaRa is only "bad midos" and Rabbinically prohibited? You do have the related aveira of Rechilus as Biblical.

Comment: @CashCow My classification is rough. This does not change the Q.

Comment: IIRC, the Chofetz Chaim brings passukim to prove that lashon hara is prohibited from the Torah @CashCow

Comment: For background:  There is a dispute in the Talmud [Yoma 86b] about whether the sins must be specified in detail in the Yom Kippur liturgy.  Rabbi Yehudah ben Baba said to specify them in detail.  But Rabbi Akiva said this is not necessary.  The matter is not resolved.  So one can do it either way.
-Ashkenazim went one way, and list 44 sins in their 'al chet' list.
-Sephardim went the other way, and list only six: 
Sins done (1) because we were forced to do them, (2) without being forced, (3) in secret, (4) in public, (5) by mistake, and (6) intentionally.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi This site lists all the sins in the Nusach Mizrach the same I brought above:http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/mizrah/kipur/shaharit.htm